# Conditional Update Query Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql

I am currently working on user management of an web application. Here, the scenario is like... I need to track online and offline users in my application. I have a users table in my database with a row "isActive" which would contain 1 if the user logs in and 0 if the user logs out.. That way, I would know who is online or who isn't ? So, I need to create a procedure which would first check the value of that column of particular user who has logged in and if its 0, would change that value to 1... How do I do that ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateUserActive(IN UserID INT, IN FromActive INT, IN ToActive INT)
BEGIN

 UPDATE Users
   SET isActive = ToActive
 WHERE isActive = FromActive
   AND UserId = UserID

END
```

Or Brute force it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateUserActive(IN UserID INT, IN ToActive INT)
BEGIN

 UPDATE Users
   SET isActive = ToActive
 WHERE UserId = UserID

END
```

Comment: thanks for reply.. but what if i have to change isActive from 1 to 0.. i mean how can i implement those both queries in a single procedure !